# Issue with multiple re-renders when adding a loading state to a Firebase callbackFlow in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-flow

I'm facing an issue when trying to add a loading state to a callbackFlow in my Firebase listener. I'm using Jetpack Compose along with a ViewModel. Without the loading state, everything works correctly, but when I attempt to include this state, multiple re-renders occur, which is not the desired behavior.

Here's a minimal example to reproduce the problem:

```
// ViewModel
class HomeScreenViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val loading = mutableStateOf(true)
    private val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    private val collection = firestore.collection("tests")

    val list: Flow<List<MyObj>>
        get() = callbackFlow {
            toggleLoading(true)
            delay(1500L)
            val listener = collection.addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
                if (error != null) return@addSnapshotListener

                val docs = value?.documents
                val myObjectList: List<MyObj>? = docs?.mapNotNull { doc ->
                    doc.toObject()
                }
                if (myObjectList != null) {
                    trySend(myObjectList)
                }
            }
            toggleLoading(false)
            awaitClose { listener.remove() }
        }

    fun toggleLoading(newVal: Boolean) {
        loading.value = newVal
    }

    // onSave, onDelete, etc. methods
}

// Composable
@Composable
fun Home() {
    val viewModel: HomeScreenViewModel = viewModel()
    val list by viewModel.list.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
    val uiLoading by viewModel.loading

    HomeContent(
        list = list,
        onSave = viewModel::onSave,
        onDelete = { id -> viewModel.onDelete(id) },
        onToggleLoading = {},
        loading = uiLoading,
    )
}
```

I would like to know where or how I could add the loading state so that it works whenever the data is updated, whether it's by deleting, adding, etc. I've considered different approaches but haven't been able to find a satisfactory solution. I appreciate any help!

Comment: I cannot see the issue at first glance but since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).